# ホームページの画像を中心に持っていきたい。

Tags: html

ホームページの画像を中心に持っていきたいです。
プログラマの方に依頼して、ページを作成していただきました。
大変素早く作っていただき、感謝しております。

基本的なコードしか知らないので、こちらは作っていただいたのをいじるぐらいです。
画像を align centerに設定しても動きません。

FTPサーバー経由でなんどもチャレンジしたのですが・・・
失敗に終わっております。

一部コードを記載します。
よろしくお願いします。

```
<div id="section-blog" class="page-section">
                <h2 class="center uppercase t300 ls3 font-body">レジュメについて</h2>
                <div class="section nobottommargin">
                    <div class="container clearfix">
                        <div class="row topmargin clearfix">
                            <div class="ipost col-sm-12 bottommargin clearfix">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <br />

                                            <p class="center"> サンプル </p> 
                                            <div class="textcenter"><img align="left" src="images/IMG_4708.JPG" alt="SAMPLE2"　height="400px" width="300px" align="center"></div>    
                                            <div class="textcenter"><img  align="rigtht" src="images/IMG_4709.JPG" alt="SAMPLE1"  height="390px" width="300px" align="center"></div> <br clear="both">  
                                     <p class="p_no_margin"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>レジュメのページ数は原則１枚です。職務歴が長い場合、ページ数が2枚でも許されています。</p>
                                     <p class="p_no_margin"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>弊社はTOP RESUMEなどの、RSSを受信し日々のアドバイスに活用させていただいております。</p>

                                 </div>                     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/106914

Answer (score 1):

img  align="rigtht"となっていますが、img align = "center"にしました。imgの部分をタグで括りました。こちらで大丈夫ですか？

```html
<div id="section-blog" class="page-section">
  <h2 class="center uppercase t300 ls3 font-body">レジュメについて</h2>
  <div class="section nobottommargin">
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="row topmargin clearfix">
        <div class="ipost col-sm-12 bottommargin clearfix">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <br />

              <p class="center"> サンプル </p>
              <div class="textcenter"><center><img align="center" src="images/IMG_4708.JPG" alt="SAMPLE2" 　height="400px" width="300px"></center></div>
              <div class="textcenter"><center><img align="center" src="images/IMG_4709.JPG" alt="SAMPLE1" height="390px" width="300px" ></center></div>
              <br clear="both">
              <p class="p_no_margin"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"> </i>レジュメのページ数は原則１枚です。職務歴が長い場合、ページ数が2枚でも許されています。</p>
              <p class="p_no_margin"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>弊社はTOP RESUMEなどの、RSSを受信し日々のアドバイスに活用させていただいております。</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```